# How to check CAA record of a domain using node.js?

Tags: node.js, dns

How can I check [the CAA(Certification Authority Authorization)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_Certification_Authority_Authorization) record of a domain using node.js?

I have found that [dnscaa](https://github.com/weppos/dnscaa) is able to check CAA record. But it's written in go.

[Node.js v9.3.0 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html) doesn't have a `resolveCaa()` function to check the CAA record of a domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I can use `dns-socket` to ask the CAA record of a domain. For example, if I want to check the CAA record of `www.google.com`, I can use the following code.

```
var dns = require('dns-socket')
var socket = dns()

socket.query({
  questions: [{
    type: 'CAA',
    name: 'google.com'
  }]
}, 53, '8.8.8.8', function (err, res) {
  console.log(res, err)
  socket.destroy()
})
```

The result would be:

```
{ id: 19712,
  type: 'response',
  flags: 384,
  questions: [ { name: 'google.com', type: 'CAA', class: 1 } ],
  answers:
   [ { name: 'google.com',
       type: 'CAA',
       class: 1,
       ttl: 21561,
       flush: false,
       data: [Object] } ],
  authorities: [],
  additionals: [] } null
```